# Do you know any result on how to interchange stochastic integration with Frechet derivative?

Tags: stochastic-integrals, frechet-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

Let we have a stochastic basis $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ with standard assumptions. Let the integral $\int_0^t f(s,h) dB_s$, for $f(s,h)$ a progressively measurable process, $h \in \mathcal{H}$ - Banach space and $f(s,\cdot)$ is Frechet differentiable for all $s \geq 0$.
Here $B = (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an $\mathbb{F}$-Brownian motion.

Does anyone know about any result to switch the Frechet derivative (denoted as $D$ and applied to $h$ component) with the stochastic integral, as
$$
D\int_0^t f(s,h) dB_s = \int_0^t Df(s,h) dB_s,
$$
and what are the conditions? some like integrability and differentiability are obvious, boundedness is a fine candidate.
I know about [this result](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ohad.kammar/notes/kammar-a-note-on-frechet-differentiation-under-lebesgue-integrals.pdf) on the same problem with Lebesgue's integration, but stochastic one looks a bit more tricky.

P.S. I was trying to describe it as self-contained as possible without going into much details, sorry for the loopholes.